# How do i get store view id from website id?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I have a website having one store and one view.
e.g)
Main Website
  Main Store
    Main View
so now i want to get Main View id from Main website id.
how can i do that?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `$website` is the instance of your website entity.
You can get the store view ids for a website like this:

```
$storeIds = $website->getStoreIds();
```

This will return an array;
If you want the first store id (the only one in your case) use `$storeIds[0]`.

**[Edit]**
If you have the website id, you can get the website object like this:

```
$website = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($websiteId);
```

then use the code above.

Comment: Thanks Marius for reply but i need a something using $websiteid instead of $website.

Comment: @user3716220. See my update.